# Dynamically replace checkbox/radio label text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there is any way to dynamically change the text of a radio label text.
And perhaps wrap the label text into a `<span>` tag, so I could further style it.

I've got the following radio button html:

```
<div class="radio-select" data-value="books-taxonomy">
   <input class="radio-input" type="radio" id="form-books-tax" name="bundle" value="books-taxonomy" checked="checked">
   <label class="radio-label" for="form-books-tax">CHANGE THIS LABEL TEXT</label>
</div>
```

This is coming directly from a plugin and unfortunately I can't just edit the html of this file.

Is there any way to achieve this? Including Jquery solution?

Comment: Can you please do check my answer whether it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not wrap a `div` by `span` instead use another `div`, you can use `wrap()`, also you can replace `label` text like this:

```js
$('.radio-select').wrap('<div class="container"></div>').find('label').text('bingo!').attr('data', 'books-taxonomy');
```

```css
.container {
  background: #5eba7d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-select" data-value="books-taxonomy">
  <input class="radio-input" type="radio" id="form-books-tax" name="bundle" value="books-taxonomy" checked="checked">
  <label class="radio-label" for="form-books-tax">CHANGE THIS LABEL TEXT</label>
</div>
```

---

**Edit:** If you want to wrap `text` inside `label` you can use `wrapInner()`:

```
$('.radio-select label').wrapInner('<span></span>').text('bingo!')
```

**Edit 2:** Also based on your comment, with what you tried, you can do:

```
 $('label[for=form-books-tax]').wrapInner('<span></span>').text('bingo!');
```

Comment: Thanks Pedram .. would it be possible to use the data-value="books-taxonomy" for the selector?

Comment: The issue that comes up now is the the .radio-select class is too broad. I've got another two radio buttons with the same class.

Comment: I am currently playing with this:
$('label[for=form-books-tax]').contents().first()[0].textContent = 'bingo!';

But unfortunately that won't work ..

Comment: @JoeBloggs Updated answer add `books-taxonomy` to target

Comment: You can change `class` too, will you?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the exact label name based on the `for` attribute in the label. Here is the solution provided. If needed you can replace the `for` attribute for dynamic replacing.

Question:

```
<div class="radio-select" data-value="books-taxonomy">
   <input class="radio-input" type="radio" id="form-books-tax" name="bundle" value="books-taxonomy" checked="checked">
   <label class="radio-label" for="form-books-tax">CHANGE THIS LABEL TEXT</label>
</div>
```

O/P:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#form-books-tax').next('label').attr("for", 'form-books-tax').text('Replace Your New Name Here');
});
```